# facebook account verification oauth login

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, user-accounts

We have developed an application in Facebook. We use a web view (python webkit) where we open the oauth url for te user to log in. Once logged user can post video/photos (via webcam) to their feed with a watermark.

We are moving around the country with this app installed on a linux computer.

The problem is that Facebook is asking our users to verify their accounts too often. Our users got tired and leave.

Is there anything we can do to improve this situation? We have asked Facebook but we are still waiting for an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like something you'll have to wait for Facebook to answer. I somewhat doubt there's a way to just "skip" verification

Comment: I think so. I know there are app whitelists but I do not know if it can help login process... thanks